# SWT CCombo not responding correctly to accessibility events (Screen Reader)

Tags: java, swt, accessibility

I've created a `CCombo` object. I've added an `AccessibilityControlListener` and overridden the `getRole(AccessibleControlEvent e)` method. The code inside the method is

```
e.detail = ACC.ROLE_COMBOBOX;
```

But the screen reader(JAWS) still reads the CCombo as **edit read only**. But it should read **combo box** since i've overridden the default role. But it dosen't seem to work. Furthermore, the CCombo object doesn't even respond to the overridden **accessiblitylistener** or **accessibilitycontrollistener** methods.

Answer (score 1):

(this is not exactly an answer, but the comment field ran out of space)

Other than most SWT widgets, `CCombo` isn't a native widget. Instead it is composed of other (native) widgets, namely a Text, a Button and a List. Apparently, not all accessibility events are overridden or redirected to the right widget.

The SWT Bugzilla lists several issues with `CCombo` and accessibility (search for 'ccombo accessibility'). Looking a the age and activity of the bugs it seems unlikely that they will be fixed anytime soon.

You might be better off using the (native) `Combo` widget if that's an option for you.

Depending on how desperate you need a fix, you could also write your own `CCombo` and fix the accessibility issues there. Of course only if all `CCombo`s are created by your code.

Knowing the internal structure of the widget, you could also attach appropriate accessibility listeners to the respective children (Text, Button, List) if that's enough to fix your issues.